# Resetting formik forms after changing user

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, formik

I have a list of users and once you click on one of them a drawer appears and some user details are displayed and below them a formik form composed of password and confirm password field if admin wants to change a certain user password,the problem is when i write something in the password field and decides to change the user selected, the password and confirm password doesn't reset to be empty insted they are still filled with what i previously written, i don't need a solution that consists of refresh after submitting the new password is entered.

```
<Formik
                    enableReinitialize={false}
                    validateOnMount={true}
                    validationSchema={passwordSchema}
                    initialValues={{ password: "", confirmPassword: "" }}
                  >
                    {formikProps => {
                      const { values, handleChange, isValid } = formikProps;
                      setDisabled(!isValid);
                      return (
                        <React.Fragment>
                          <Grid item xs={6} md={7}>
                            <TextField
                              margin="normal"
                              autoFocus
                              className={clsx(
                                classes.textField,
                                classes.margin
                              )}
                              required
                              id="password"
                              name="password"
                              label={<Translate i18nKey="password" />}
                              fullWidth
                              value={values.password || ""}
                              onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
                            />
                          </Grid>
                          <Grid item xs={6} md={7}>
                            <TextField
                              margin="normal"
                              autoFocus
                              className={clsx(
                                classes.textField,
                                classes.margin
                              )}
                              required
                              id="confirm_password"
                              name="confirmPassword"
                              label={<Translate i18nKey="re_enter_password" />}
                              fullWidth
                              value={values.confirmPassword || ""}
                              onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
                            />
                          </Grid>
                          <Button
                            className={classes.btn}
                            onClick={(event, password) =>
                              modifyPassword(values.password)
                            }
                            variant="contained"
                            color="primary"
                            position=""
                          >
                            Change Password
                          </Button>
                        </React.Fragment>
                      );
                    }}
                  </Formik>
```

and i m using the react hooks to contain the user details the useEffect hook to update each time the user details but i need it to reset the password fields in addition

```
useEffect(() => {
    setState(event);
  }, [event]);
```

the modifyPassword funtion takes care of submitting the new password.

Answer (score 0):

You have set `enableReinitialize=true` (this allow you to modify the initialValues whenever it changed)

then modify your `initialValues` to be one of the useState
eg:

```
const [userState,setUserState] = useState({
 password:'',
 confirmPassword:''
})

// your formik component...
<Formik
enableReinitialize={true} // changes here
validateOnMount={true}
validationSchema={passwordSchema}
initialValues={userState} // changes here
... > ... </Formik>
```

then in your `useEffect` when your user change simply call

```
setUserState({
 password:'',
 confirmPassword:''})
```

Your formik will reset state. The idea is there. Or instead of useEffect you may call the setUserState to default value whenever your user is changed.

Hope it helps.

Edited

for having the same password and confirm password, 
It may because of the handleChange(dont think material UI works out of box with formik)

```
const { values, handleChange, isValid, setFieldValue } = formikProps;
setDisabled(!isValid);

 // add this
const myHandleChange = (e)=>{
 const {name,value} = e.target;
 setFieldValue(name,value)
}
return (...)
```

Then, in your `onChange={myHandleChange}`

Comment: thank you but i still have the same issue the password and the confirm password always contain the same values

Comment: Khalil I have edited my answer, see the edited part

Comment: the problem is that the values of password when i console.log them they are always emptyString now matter how much i fill them even though I did as you mentioned